# If you disable multicast loopback, can you send and receive on the same multicast group?

Tags: c++, multicast

Imagine there is process `A` and processes `B` and `C`, and I want all of them to multicast out messages to group `X.Y.Z.W` on port `P`, and `A` is simultaneously listening to those messages on that group. Is it possible for `A` to receive the messages from `B` and `C` without receiving it's own? In other words, if I disable loopback (in order for `A` not to receive the messages it is multicasting) will it still receive the messages from `B` and `C` or will this effectively result in it no longer even listening to `X.Y.Z.W` on port `P`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work as you describe. We're using this in RSP[1] in exactly the same way for any-to-any reliable multicast.

[1] http://www.equalizergraphics.com/documents/design/multicast.html#RSP

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell from the documentation, the `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP` option operates at the host level, not the individual socket. So if you disable it, no processes on the sending host will receive the multicast packets; if you enable it, all processes on the sending host will receive it.

What A can do is check the source IP and port of the packets it receives. If they match the local IP and port of its sending socket, it should ignore them.

Comment: @PalaceChan This answer is not correct and it appears to be based on guesswork rather than experience or knowledge. Disabling `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP` only prevents you from receiving multicasts you sent yourself from the same host. You will still receive multicasts from other sources. Nothing in any documentation I have ever seen suggests otherwise. @eile's answer is correct.

Comment: @ejp I googled and checked a number of webpages, and they all said "same host", not "same process" or "same socket".

Comment: In other words you are still guessing. Have you ever *tried* it? Multicast loopback is an option that affects *sending* from *the socket you call it on.*

Comment: @ejp There's a difference between guessing and researching. I'd delete my answer, but it won't let me since he accepted it.

Comment: Just using search engines isn't researching. To qualify as true research there would have to be a critical experiment.

Comment: I disagree with EJP. The specification is unclear, and reading manpages is indeed research. FreeBSD says this: If a multicast datagram is sent to a group to which the sending host itself belongs (on the outgoing interface), a copy of the datagram is, by default, looped back by the IP layer for local delivery.  The IP_MULTICAST_LOOP option gives the sender explicit control over whether or not subsequent datagrams are looped back.